# GAS loop "for" and call function

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to optimise something. My script:

```
function d1() {     
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {    
     d1();     
   }     
   Logger.log("DONE!");   
 }

 function d2() {    
   for (i = 1; i < 2; i++)       
     Logger.log("IN PROGRESS...");     
 }
```

This script will never complete! But if I change to

```
function d1() {
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (i = 1; i < 2; i++)
      Logger.log("IN PROGRESS...");
  }
  Logger.log("DONE!");
}
```

Everything perfect! What's my problem?

Oh, I'm stupid. of course I call d2().

My script is completely different, I tried to simplify, but I guess I'd better send the original, I hope it will be clear.

projects.gs

```
 function ViewNewProjects() { 

  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  

  var wait = app.getElementById("wait");  
  wait.setStyleAttribute("display","none");

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AnYzxNSJL2u_dDVETm9JNVAxQ3BESmdoNGZnc1JDN2c");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Заявки Технического Отдела");
  var data = app.getElementById("Data_Panel");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var bg = true;

  data.clear();

  for (i=2; i<values.length; i++) {

    var row = app.createHorizontalPanel();

    var techSpec = app.createHTML(values[i][4]);
    var status = app.createHTML(values[i][11]);

    if (values[i][4].length == 0 && values[i][12] != "Закрыт") {

      var projectLabel = app.createHTML(values[i][0] + ", " + values[i][2]);
      var typeLabel = app.createHTML(values[i][1]);
      var postLabel = app.createHTML(values[i][5]);
      var startDateLabel = app.createHTML(values[i][6]);
      **var expDateLabel = app.createHTML(EstimateData(values[i][7]));**
      var buttonGet = app.createButton("Взять проект");

      var getProject = app.createServerHandler("ViewProject");
      var ShowWait = app.createServerHandler("ShowWait"); 

      projectLabel.setId("project_id_" + i);
      projectLabel.addClickHandler(ShowWait);
      projectLabel.addClickHandler(getProject);

      row.setWidth("100%");

      projectLabel.setStyleAttribute("margin", "3"); 
      projectLabel.setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px"); 

      typeLabel.setStyleAttribute("margin", "3"); 
      typeLabel.setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px"); 

      postLabel.setStyleAttribute("margin", "3"); 
      postLabel.setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px");

      startDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("margin", "3"); 
      startDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px");

      expDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("margin", "3"); 
      expDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px");

      if (bg == true) {

        projectLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#e9e9e9");
        typeLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#e9e9e9");
        postLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#e9e9e9");
        startDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#e9e9e9");
        expDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#e9e9e9");

        bg = false;

      } else {

        projectLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#f9f9f9");
        typeLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#f9f9f9");
        postLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#f9f9f9");
        startDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#f9f9f9");
        expDateLabel.setStyleAttribute("background-color", "#f9f9f9");

        bg = true;

      }

      projectLabel.setStyleAttribute("cursor", "pointer");  
      projectLabel.setStyleAttribute("color", "blue");  
      projectLabel.setStyleAttribute("text-decoration", "underline"); 

      row.add(projectLabel)
         .add(typeLabel)
         .add(postLabel)
         .add(startDateLabel)
         .add(expDateLabel)
         .add(buttonGet);

      row.setCellHorizontalAlignment(projectLabel, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
      row.setCellVerticalAlignment(projectLabel, UiApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
      row.setCellWidth(projectLabel, "320px");

      row.setCellHorizontalAlignment(typeLabel, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
      row.setCellVerticalAlignment(typeLabel, UiApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
      row.setCellWidth(typeLabel, "120px");

      row.setCellHorizontalAlignment(postLabel, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
      row.setCellVerticalAlignment(postLabel, UiApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
      row.setCellWidth(postLabel, "200px");

      row.setCellHorizontalAlignment(startDateLabel, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
      row.setCellVerticalAlignment(startDateLabel, UiApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
      row.setCellWidth(startDateLabel, "80px");

      row.setCellHorizontalAlignment(expDateLabel, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
      row.setCellVerticalAlignment(expDateLabel, UiApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
      row.setCellWidth(expDateLabel, "80px");

      row.setCellHorizontalAlignment(buttonGet, UiApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
      row.setCellVerticalAlignment(buttonGet, UiApp.VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);

      data.add(row);

    }

  }

  return app;

 };
```

holidays.gs

```
function EstimateData(date_to_estimate) {

  var date = new Date();
  var count = 0;

  var mounth = new String(date.getMonth() + 1);
  var day = new String(date.getDate());
  var year = new String(date.getFullYear());

  if (mounth < 10)

    mounth = new String("0" + mounth);

  var current_date = year + mounth + day;

  var ___date_to_estimate = new String(date_to_estimate);
  var date_to_estimate_array = ___date_to_estimate.match(/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/); 
  var ___date_to_estimate = date_to_estimate_array[3] + date_to_estimate_array[2] + date_to_estimate_array[1];

  current_date = Number(current_date);
  ___date_to_estimate = Number(___date_to_estimate);

  if (current_date > ___date_to_estimate) {

    Logger.log("Текущая дата больше рассчитываемой");

    var difference = Number(current_date - ___date_to_estimate);

    Logger.log("Разница " + difference);

    if (difference == 0) {

      return date_to_estimate;

    } else if (difference < 31) {

      var weekday = date.getDay();

      Logger.log("День недели " + weekday);

      for (i = 1; i < difference; i++) {

        if (weekday == 7)

          weekday = 0;

        if (weekday > 0 && weekday < 6) {

          count++;

        }

        weekday++;

      }

    } else if (difference < 1130) {

    } else {

    }


  } else if (current_date == ___date_to_estimate) {

    date_to_estimate = '<b>Сегодня!!!</b>';

  } else {

  }

  Logger.log("Количество рабочих дней " + count);

  return date_to_estimate;

}
```

while writing the message and testing, I found my mistake.

loop for in projects.gs contain variable i
loop for in holadays.gs contain varialble i too

I changed the variable and it's all right!

Comment: i forget. function b1 called by button on page.

Answer (score 1):

You have infinite recursion because you are calling `d1()` inside of `d1()` for loop.

Your first function should be

```
function d1() {     
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {    
     d2();     
   }     
   Logger.log("DONE!");   
 }
```